# Changing significance notation in R

Tags: r, lm

R has certain significance codes to determine statistical significance. In the example below, for example, a dot `.` indicates significance at the 10% level (see sample output below).

Dots can be very hard to see, especially when I copy-paste to Excel and display it in Times New Roman.

I'd like to change it such that:

- `*` = significant at 10%
- `**` = significant at 5%
- `***` = significant at 1%

Is there a way I can do this?

```
> y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
> x = c(1,3,2,4,5,6,8,7)
> summary(lm(y~x))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.0714 -0.3333  0.0000  0.2738  1.1191 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.2143     0.6286   0.341  0.74480    
x             0.9524     0.1245   7.651  0.00026 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8067 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.907, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8915 
F-statistic: 58.54 on 1 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.0002604
```

Comment: That's printed by the `stats:::printCoefmat` and it has those values hard-coded in there. You can format p-values with your own symbols by calling `symnum()` but the default options for `summary.lm` don't seem to be configurable. Are you really pasting these results into Excel?? Yuck.

Comment: Basically copy-pasting the coefficients, then using the "Text to columns" feature to make everything neat.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting symnum, I'll check that out.

Comment: There are frequently questions about the stars, either in reconfiguring the breaks or in over-confidence in them. The latter point was [published in the American Statistics Association](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108) as a caution against over- or mis-use of *p*-values. I've even seen (unofficial) mention of trying to remove them from the `lm` summary report, though I can't find those refs at the moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create your own formatting function with

```
mystarformat <- function(x) symnum(x, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
    cutpoints = c(0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), 
    symbols = c("***", "**", "*", " "))
```

And you can write your own coefficient formatter

```
show_coef <- function(mm) {
     mycoef<-data.frame(coef(summary(mm)), check.names=F)
     mycoef$signif = mystarformat(mycoef$`Pr(>|t|)`)
     mycoef$`Pr(>|t|)` = format.pval(mycoef$`Pr(>|t|)`)
     mycoef
}
```

And then with your model, you can run it with

```
mm <- lm(y~x)
show_coef(mm)
#              Estimate Std. Error   t value  Pr(>|t|) signif
# (Intercept) 0.2142857  0.6285895 0.3408993 0.7447995       
# x           0.9523810  0.1244793 7.6509206 0.0002604    ***
```

Comment: Though highly unlikely, a *p*-value of 0 will return `NA` (since `cut` breaks by default are closed on the left). You can mitigate that by changing your first cut point from 0 to "something less".

Comment: @r2evans I basically did the same thing `stats:::printCoefmat` there as well so I guess the default `print.summary.lm` would have the same problem.

Comment: So true, good point. I guess none of my statistical results have ever been "perfectly-significant".

Comment: @r2evans Actually `mystarformat(0)` returns "***" so i guess it's just the fact that `symnum` is different than `cut`

Comment: Ahhh, I see the reference to `any(ii <- is.na(iS))` in `symnum` at line 68 of [`symnum.R`](https://svn.r-project.org/R/tags/R-3-3-3/src/library/stats/R/symnum.R). Sorry, premature mitigation :-)

Answer (score 1):

One should be aware that stargazer package reports significance levels with a different scale than other statistical softwares like STATA.

In R (stargazer) you get `# (* p<0.1; ** p<0.05; *** p<0.01)`. Whereas, in STATA you get `# (* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p< 0.001)`.

This means that what is significant with one * in R results may appear not to be significant for a STATA user.

Comment: BTW, you can change the cutoffs in stargazer package to make it like other softwares' outputs, in case you work with co-authors for example:

stargazer(output, output2, type = "html", 
          star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001)) # star.cutoffs = NULL by default

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, but I found a great solution to this. 
Just do the following:

```
install.packages("stargazer")
library(stargazer)
stargazer(your_regression, type = "text")
```

This displays everything in a beautiful way with your desired format. 
Note: If you leave `type = "text"` out, then you'll get the LaTeX code.